# Url Routing by Deep Linking from App Component

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm trying to route by url from app.component.ts in ionic.

```
my-site.com/parse/this/data
```

In a page component, I can do this by deep linking with -

```
@IonicPage({
   segment: "my-component/:param1/:param2/:param3"
})
```

But then url includes the segment - my-site.com/#/my-component/:param1...

I just tried to add NavParams to app.component.ts and it threw an exception when trying to deep link. Without having to mess with url rewrites, is there a way to do this out of the box from the main app component so I get the root base?

Thanks,

Comment: So you want remove the `#`?

Comment: Well, both the # and the page segment.

Comment: You can do it by **not** use lazy load.

Comment: Couldnt get it to work using deeplinking  w/o lazy loading - 

   imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
      locationStrategy: 'path'
    }, {
      links: [{
        segment: '/:param1/:param2/:param3',
        name: 'root',
        component: HomePage
      }]
    })
  ],